# Send data to php server from Python

Tags: python, php, sql

I have a php script on server side that collects data and inserts into MySQL database ;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_marks (value) VALUES ('".$_GET["value"]."')";
```

I can add values from browser without issues as such ;

```
http://localhost/write.php?value=100
```

But I can't post from Python using requests ;

```
r = requests.post('https://localhost/write.php?', data = {'value':'100'})
```

There are no errors or warnings but I see that no entries are written to the table from Python. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: ```print(r.status_code)``` check if your POST message was successful?

Comment: Have you debugged your POST object to see what the result was?

Comment: you're using `https` in your python code. was that a typo.

Comment: status_code returns "200". Yes http-https difference was a typo, sorry

Comment: I searched around and tried all the methods like mimicing a browser with header but still issue remains. Anyone encountered similar behavior ? At response of Python : >This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support.    How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP you submitted is looking at GET values (Directly from the user by the way. Look into SQL injection attacks), but your python is making a POST request. Try this instead:

```
r = requests.get('http://localhost/write.php', params={'value': '100'})
```